# Arduino Socket.io Communicate

Tags: node.js, socket.io, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266

How can i send Data from Socket.io (NodeJs Server) to arduino ? 
I have a ESP8266 Wifi Shield ,  Can i send and receive  data ? If i can there is any basic example for it ? How can i use the Arduino Socket Client ? 
I find like this example

Can I Use like this ?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

#include "SocketIOClient.h"

SocketIOClient client;

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
char hostname[] = "";

// Socket.io "chat_message" event handler
void chat_message(EthernetClient ethclient, char *data ){
  Serial.print("Message : ");
  Serial.println(data);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  Serial.print("Arduino is on ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

  if(client.connect(hostname, 3000, "socket.io", "/chat_room")) {
    Serial.println("Socket.IO connected !");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Socket.IO not connected.");
  }

  //Event hanlders
  client.setEventHandler("chat_message",  chat_message);

  //Say hello! to the server
  client.emit("chat_message", "Arduino here, hello!");
}

void loop() {
  client.monitor();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket.IO is an API for WebSockets and most of Websocket libraries are supporting it.

I am pretty happy with this most contributed [Arduino WebSocket library](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets) and it also supports Socket.IO. Here is your [Socket.IO example](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets/blob/529a86cc26cff78896f6627bd9475d6060a36df5/examples/WebSocketClientSocketIO/WebSocketClientSocketIO.ino).

Here is a heartbeat message type of socket.io implementaiton from the example:

```
if((now - heartbeatTimestamp) > HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL) {
    heartbeatTimestamp = now;
    // socket.io heartbeat message
    webSocket.sendTXT("2");
}
```

Comment: abi sana ulaşabileceğim bir kapı var mıdır acaba ? :(

Comment: Solved your problem? @Ahmad

Comment: Yok abi çözüm bulamadım @cagdas yapamadım

Comment: Very useful info.